# "Null" value while retrieving data from intent in kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, android-intent

I am passing some value through intent from `FirstActivity` to `MainActivity`. But, when I try to retrieve that value from second activity (i.e. MainActivity) I am not able to do so.

**FirstActivity**

```
 var i = Intent()
        launcher?.launch(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        i.putExtra("key", cold)
        startActivity(i)
```

**MainActivity**

```
val initialCold = intent.getStringExtra("key")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line `launcher?.launch(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))` this is another intent, not `i` and you launched it without the extra key string, so you can't get it in your MainActivity, the right way if you want to launch activity for result

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("key", cold)
launcher?.launch(intent)
```

Or like this if you want to start the MainActivity without result

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Thank's! Now is clear!

Comment: You're welcome :D